# How to structure the speech of one character when it consists of two linked but independent phrases

Tags: grammar, punctuation, commas, capitalization, speech

If you were writing a quote structured like this...
'You were right Izzy!', said Ted, 'there is something we can do.'

… would be correct to have a fullstop after 'Ted' and a capital letter for 'there' (because it is two separate phrases) or would it be correct to write it as I have typed it above (because they are still spoken by the same person and so are connected, and a capital is not required)?

Also, would this alter if the example were something like 
'It's no use,' said Fred, 'go on without me.' (e.g. would that need a full stop and a capital after 'Fred', or does the above work?)

Thank you!

Comment: I would probably use 'You were right Izzy!', said Ted. 'There is something we can do.'  The first sentence ends with "!", so "There" begins a new sentence.  And you maintain continuity of speaker by keeping it all in a single paragraph, starting a new paragraph when speakers change.

Comment: While the modern relaxed approach (others still exist!) to punctuation would allow 'You were right Izzy!' said Ted, 'there is something we can do.' (double punctuation is a last resort for clarification, but sentence-medial exclamation and question marks are used by fine authors), splitting into two sentences is less messy. But you may prefer the less staccato effect of the comma ....

Comment: You need to think how you would punctuate "'It's no use [?] go on without me." Sans "said Fred". What replaces [?]? If you're OK with a comma, then it can be one sentence, if you think that's wrong, then you'd split it into 2 sentences. It's a judgment call.

Answer (score 1):

Taking your "Fred" example:

> "It's no use," said Fred. "Go on without me."

The more common style is to end the first phrase by identifying who is speaking, and ending that as a complete phrase with a period. This makes it so the next dialogue phrase begins with a capital letter. If they are related phrases, they stay in the same line.

Also consider this (expanding on your example):

> "It's no use," said Fred. "Go on without me. I can't keep up."

The pattern stays the same even if there is additional dialogue.

Comment: It's fine to split a sentence with "said Fred", but it does need to be grammatically a single sentence that doesn't require a semicolon or full stop; in this case it's questionable.